# PushWoosh - Location based notifications via Remote API

Tags: php, pushwoosh, remoteapi

I am looking to filter notifications based on users current location. I get that I can set geozones through the PushWoosh web-site, but I can't seem to find any way to do this through the remote API.

I want to do something like this:

```
$this->pwCall('createMessage', 
    array
    (
    'application' => 'XXXXX-XXXXX',
    'auth' => 'XXXXXX[...]',
    'lng' => 42,
    'lat' => 42,
    'range' => 1000,
    'notifications' => array
        (
            array
            (
                "platforms" => array(3),
                'send_date' => 'now',
                "ignore_user_timezone" => true,
                'content' => "$message",
                'data' => array("type" => $type),
                "android_header" => "$header",
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In other words: Send the notification to any device within a certain range from a specific location, but I can't get it to work. Is it even possible to do something like this?

Thank you in advance!